# How do I make a new line or tab in <string> XML?

Tags: android, xml, tabs, newline

In my `strings.xml` file I have a very long text which I want to format.

How can I put a tab before the first sentence of the text? Also, what is the code for new line?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938403/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-in-xml-string-resources-in-android/31683548#31683548

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Add `\t` for tab and `\n` for new line.

Comment: How can I make two break lines?

Comment: @jvargas \n\n you are permitted to sequence them as much as needed

Comment: I find android studio will often strip any '\n' out of my string files, particularly after using the translation editor. Very irritating.

Comment: Also using `&#10;` works as well in xml attributes

Answer (score 41):

Use `\n` for a line break and `\t` if you want to insert a tab.

You can also use some XML tags for basic formatting: `<b>` for bold text, `<i>` for italics, and `<u>` for underlined text

More info:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 39):

**\n** didn't work for me. So I used `<br/>` HTML tag

```
<string name="message_register_success">
    Sign up is complete. <br/>
    Enjoy a new shopping life at fatherofapps.com!!
</string>
```

Comment: In the layout, you can see the \n to be visible but while running \n converts into a new line on the actual device and the <br/> looks a new line in layout but in actual device it is visible as <br/>

Answer (score 25):

Use \t to add tab and \n for new line, here is a simple example below.

```
<string name="list_with_tab_tag">\tbanana\torange\tblueberry\tmango</string>
<string name="sentence_with_new_line_tag">This is the first sentence\nThis is the second scentence\nThis is the third sentence</string>
```

Answer (score 18):

add this line at the top of string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and use

```
'\n'
```

from where you want to break your line.

ex. `<string> Hello world. \n its awesome. <string>`

Output:

```
Hello world.
its awesome.
```

Comment: How can I make two break lines?

Comment: T wo break lines '\n\n'

Comment: Kudos for including the encoding at the top

Answer (score 13):

You can use `\n` for new line and `\t` for tabs. Also, extra spaces/tabs are just copied the way you write them in `Strings.xml` so just give a couple of spaces where ever you want them.

A better way to reach this would probably be using padding/margin in your view xml and splitting up your long text in different strings in your `string.xml`

Comment: Accept someone's answer if you're helped ;)

Answer (score 8):

`\n` doesn't seem to work for `tools:text`

You can use `<br/>` to get a preview including line breaks, but it won't show up on the device unless you format the text using something like `Html.fromHtml()`

Comment: In the layout, you can see the \n to be visible but while running \n converts into a new line on the actual device and the <br/> looks a new line in layout but in actual device it is visible as <br/>

Comment: You are right, edited. Is \n seriously something that tools:text can't handle?

Comment: Forget about `tools:text`, if you used \n for `android:text`, it would still be visible as \n in the layout preview on android studio.
But when you run it on an actual device, the \n converts to a new line.

Answer (score 8):

for space use `\t` and for a new line use `\n` in your XML string, like

```
<string name="name">\tFirst Sentence\nSecond Sentence</string>
```

the output will be

```
    First Sentence
Second Sentence
```

Answer (score 3):

Add '\t' for tab

```
<string name="tab">\u0009</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Include this line in your layout `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
- Now , use `\n` for new line and `\t` for space like tab.
- Example :

  for **\n** :  `android:text="Welcome back ! \nPlease login to your account agilanbu"`

  for **\t** :  `android:text="Welcome back ! \tPlease login to your account agilanbu"`

Comment: How can I make two break lines?

Comment: @jvargas make it \n\n

Answer (score 2):

Really all of the above did not work for me in Android Studio 4.
What worked was:

```
<br>first line\n</br>second line
```

Note: Both \n and br-tags was needed.