# How to format the following string in strings.xml

Tags: android, formatting, android-xml

I have the following string:

☑ REKT

☑ Really Rekt

☑ Tyrannosaurus Rekt

I copy and pasted this into the `strings.xml` file but when it is displayed on screen it ends up looking like a jumbled mess.

[image]

How can I format this in `strings.xml` so it maintains its original list look.

(Ignore the hand at the beginning, that was from something else).

Update:

Doing `☑ REKT  \n ☑ Really Rekt ☑ \n Tyrannosaurus Rekt \n` produced this result:

[image]

Update Two: It seems to be a problem with the checkboxes. When I removed them the string acted fine. Unfortunately, I need the checkboxes.

Comment: Are you asking [how to have tabs and newlines in a string resource](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14091780/115145)?

Comment: @CommonsWare No, I tried using the traditional newlines method but it just produced a odd result.

Comment: Perhaps your problem is not in the string resource, but in how you are applying it (e.g., gravity in the `TextView`).

Comment: @CommonsWare I am making a custom keyboard, so I can't set any gravity. When a key is pressed on the keyboard the following code runs:                `getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(inputText,1);` where `inputText` is the string.

Comment: The app that has the `EditText` (or whatever is using the keyboard) will do what it wants with your text. You do not control that. At most, you control your keyboard itself.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine for me with the newline characters. I displayed it in a TextView inside RelativeLayout. I realize I am quite late, but for examples like this one you need to provide more context for people to be able to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

☑ REKT\n☑ Really Rekt\n☑ Tyrannosaurus Rekt

Adding line breaks should work

Comment: @MDubzem. This did not work, I'll post the result in my post.